# What's `irb` meaning? and what's the difference between it and `vlan`?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

What's `irb` meaning? and what's the difference between `vlan`?

I found some Junos version the vlan l3-interfaces should be `vlan.xxx`, and some times there is `irb.xxx`.

[image]

```
irb {
    unit 0 {
        family inet;
    }
    unit 2 {
        family inet {
            address 10.10.10.254/24;
        }
    }
    unit 9 {
        family inet {
            address 1.1.1.14/29;
        }
    }
    unit 10 {
        family inet {
            address 1.1.1.22/29;
        }
    }
    unit 11 {
        family inet {
```

Comment: Please, never use an image for text. Simply copy the text and paste it into the question using the Preformatted-text feature (`{}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Enhanced Layer-2 Switching (ELS)

Juniper has a couple of different product lines (routers, switches, firewalls) that theoretically run the same operating system (Junos). However, software for these product lines is developed separately from each other, and as a result the configuration syntax for similar features (mainly layer-2 stuff) ended up being different on routers (MX platform) and switches (EX platform). This is obviously a bit confusing for people running both types of devices.

In 2013, Juniper introduced a new configuration syntax for EX switches (starting with Junos 13.2) to remedy this: [Enhanced Layer-2 Software (ELS)](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/topic-map/layer-2-understanding.html#id-using-the-enhanced-layer-2-software-cli). This syntax is similar to the syntax used on MX routers. One of the changes in the new syntax is renaming vlan interfaces from `vlan.xx` to `irb.xx`. You can find a complete list of all changes on the [juniper.net website](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/topic-map/layer-2-understanding.html#id-understanding-els-configuration-statement-and-command-changes).

In general, older EX switches (EX-2200, EX-3300, EX-4200, ...) still use the old style configuration syntax. Newer devices (EX-2300, EX-4300, ...) use the new syntax. The same is true for branch SRX firewalls: SRX-2xx uses the old style, SRX-3xx uses ELS syntax. Check the [Juniper Feature Explorer](https://apps.juniper.net/feature-explorer/feature-info.html?fKey=5890&fn=Uniform+Enhanced+Layer+2+Software+(ELS)+CLI+configuration+statements+and+operational+commands) for an authoritative list of all devices and software releases that use the ELS syntax.

## Integrated Routing and Bridging (IRB)

Integrated Routing and Bridging (IRB) is a pretty common term used by both [Cisco](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/iosxr/ncs5500/interfaces/61x/b-ncs5500-interfaces-configuration-guide-61x/b-ncs5500-interfaces-configuration-guide-61x_chapter_01100.pdf) and [Juniper](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/topic-map/irb-and-bridging.html) for layer-3 VLAN interfaces. Other terms for pretty much the same concept are:

- VLAN interface
- Routed VLAN interface (RVI)
- Bridge-Group Virtual Interface (BVI)

Answer (score 2):

Juniper introduced a new "variant" of JunOS for some devices and called it [ELS (Enhanced Layer 2 Software)](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/topic-map/layer-2-understanding.html#id-using-the-enhanced-layer-2-software-cli). The idea is to unify the CLI syntax between different platforms running Junos. This changed the syntax for a few commands, including switching from `vlan` to `irb` for virtual L3 interfaces. This is the same syntax that is used for Juniper router platforms. There is also [a list of changes](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/topic-map/layer-2-understanding.html#id-understanding-els-configuration-statement-and-command-changes) for the ELS CLI.